# how to convert python dictionary into parent-child relation?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
input_dictionary= {'A': [{'B1': [{'C1': ['D2']}, {'C2': ['D3']}]}, {'B2': [{'C1': ['D2']}, {'C2': ['D3']}]}]}
```

Output:

```
['A','A_B1','A_B2','A_B1_C1','A_B1,C2',.....so on]
```

So, the generic format is parent_child_subchild and so on.
Any advice/guideline would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: try looking at the `for` loop [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: @huapito No actually I want a recursive approach. I tried DFS approach and able to traverse all the nodes but I am not able to figure out how to print the output in the format : parent_child_subchild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> def stringify(d, prefix=[]):
...     try:
...        for k,l in d.items():
...            return ['_'.join(prefix+[k])]+[f for e in l for f in stringify(e,prefix+[k])]
...     except AttributeError:
...         return ['_'.join(prefix+[d])]
...
>>> stringify(input_dictionary)
['A', 'A_B1', 'A_B1_C1', 'A_B1_C1_D2', 'A_B1_C2', 'A_B1_C2_D3', 'A_B2', 'A_B2_C1', 'A_B2_C1_D2', 'A_B2_C2', 'A_B2_C2_D3']
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm.